# Method to work with bitwise isolated "1s" from an unsigned long long in C++, works in C# but creates strange results in C++

Tags: c#, c++, chess, unsigned

I'm transferring my chess engine from C# to C++ to get a higher performance. I am using bitboards (unsigned long long's) for each chess piece, representing where they are located. So when looking bitwise at one of these unsigned long longs each one represents a piece, each zero an empty square.

I start with sending the unsigned long long array entry representing a piece to another unsigned long long:
unsigned long long r = position[2]

When I count the "1's" in r my method returns 2, which means there are two bishops, that is true.

```
while r != 0
{

// I have been using a method which counts the Trailing zeros, p locates where the first "1"     lies:

unsigned long long i = r;
unsigned long long y;
            unsigned long long n = 63;
            y = i << 32; if (y != 0) { n = n - 32; i = y; }
            y = i << 16; if (y != 0) { n = n - 16; i = y; }
            y = i << 8; if (y != 0) { n = n - 8; i = y; }
            y = i << 4; if (y != 0) { n = n - 4; i = y; }
            y = i << 2; if (y != 0) { n = n - 2; i = y; }
            int p = n - ((i << 1) >> 63);

/*The method works and for example returns 58 for the bishops, meaning the first bishop is        situated on square 59. Then I'm doing stuff with this position, to estimate the possible moves of  that piece, but that doesn't matter here.
Next, and that is where the problem occurs, I take away the first '1' from r:
*/

r -= (1UL << p)
}
```

When I now count the "1's" in r my method returns 33, while it should return one, as I subtracted one of the two bishops.
The most curious thing is that when I use the same code in C# (with slighly changes, unsigned long long is ulong, etc.) the method works.

I tried to use different data types for p or deleted the "UL" in "(1UL << p)". But I couldn't think of any problems with the code. It seems to by a very simple silly mistake.

Comment: i don't know why this got downvoted. There is a better bitcounting algorithm, though.

Comment: Why `r -= (1UL << p)` instead of `r -= (1ULL << p)`?

Comment: I just edited the question, of course it's r -= (1UL << p) not r = (1UL << p)

Comment: but 1UL is only 32bits. Need 1ULL

Comment: Ok, that was the problem. In C# the UInt64 is called UL not ULL. Solved. Thanks!

Comment: Note: In C++ `unsigned long long` need not be 64 bit. It cannot be smaller than 64 bit, but the upper bound is implementation defined. Probably not a problem for you... yet. Prefer to use `uint64_t` from `<cstdint>` because you'll always get 64 bits or the program won't compile.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey -- `1UL` is **at least** 32 bits. It can be larger. But, of course, `1ULL` is still the right thing.

Comment: If you have C++ 20 or later use [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount).

Comment: "from C# to C++ to get a higher performance" C# can be high performance if you know what you're doing. And certainly for bit-twiddling the performance will be almost the same.

Comment: @user - Specifically for a chess program - if you *ever* try to run this on anything other than a 64-bit CPU you will have to rewrite the bitmap code from scratch, or it will just suck performance-wise. Using `uint64_t` will not help you.

Comment: Even if the CPU has more than 64 bit? An unsigned long long is just so useful because the field is 64 squares.

Comment: @Paul Where BoP is headed is if you want speed, you use the CPU's basic unsigned integer type. For example, if it's a 256 bit CPU, you burn 4 times the space in favour of higher performance ([probably use `uint_fast64_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)).

Comment: You can use `BitOperations.PopCount` which should be pretty efficient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.popcount?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-bitoperations-popcount(system-uint64) Which CPU are you using that has a larger than 64-bit native int size?

Comment: The PopCount I used was just to find out what is wrong with the method. I have a 64 bit CPU, I was just asking what would happen if it's larger.